# Reporting services-milliseconds to dd:hh:mm

Tags: reporting, mdx

I'm making a report in Reporting services. I have a column in milliseconds and I want to make it as dd:hh:mm.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft Analysis Services you can use any VBA function in your MDX, so the whole range of string and date formatting methods are available to you. Perhaps start your MDX with:

`WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyNewName] AS 'FormatDateTime([Measures].[MyExistingName], something-or-other)'`

Alternatively, Google `FORMAT_STRING` and see if that can help.